# SQL Server SUM IF using Window function with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

EDIT: Original question name 'SQL Server SUM records only Group By certain values'. Refined, since know now what to look for.

I am currently trying to aggregate based on conditions using `OVER` and `PARITION BY`, However I don't know how to integrate the last condition.

What it should do:
IF per `CONTRACTID`, `VALIDFROM`, `VALIDTO` there is a value 'H104' within column `RENTALCOSTTYPEID`
THEN aggregate all `AMOUNT` that have `RENTALCOSTTYPEID` values that start with 'H'. ELSE show `AMOUNT` without aggregation.

My current code works when per `CONTRACTID`, `VALIDFROM`, `VALIDTO` there is a value 'H104'. However, if per `CONTRACTID`, `VALIDFROM`, `VALIDTO` there is not a value 'H104' it gives '0' instead of the `AMOUNT`
Looking at the code it obviously puts '0', but if I change this value, it messes with the fields where there is a value 'H104'. How can I integrate this condition in the following code?

```
SELECT
CONTRACTID
,RENTALCOSTTYPEID
,VALIDFROM
,VALIDTO
,AMOUNT
,CASE 
    WHEN RENTALCOSTTYPEID = 'H104' 
    THEN SUM(CASE WHEN RENTALCOSTTYPEID LIKE 'H%' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0  END) OVER (PARTITION BY CONTRACTID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO) 
    ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN RENTALCOSTTYPEID LIKE 'H%' THEN 0 ELSE AMOUNT  END) OVER (PARTITION BY RENTALCOSTTYPEID, CONTRACTID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO)
END AS TESTCOLUMN
FROM PMCCONTRACTLINE
```

Column `CURRENT` holds the results I currently have

Column `ENDRESULT` holds the results I want it to be

```
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| CONTRACTID | RENTALCOSTTYPEID | VALIDFROM  | VALIDTO    | AMOUNT  | CURRENT | ENDRESULT |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC018453   | H104             | 2020-07-01 | 2021-01-01 | 775.08  | 446.72  | 446.72    |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC018453   | H110             | 2020-07-01 | 2021-01-01 | -328.36 | 0.00    | 0.00      |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC018453   | V446             | 2020-07-01 | 2021-01-01 | 48.00   | 48.00   | 48.00     |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC055533   | H105             | 2020-07-01 | 2021-01-01 | 330.00  | 0.00    | 330.00    |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC055533   | H105H            | 2019-07-01 | 2020-06-30 | 330.00  | 0.00    | 330.00    |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC103696   | H104             | 2020-06-03 | 2021-01-01 | 867.00  | 867.00  | 867.00    |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC103696   | S468             | 2020-06-03 | 2021-01-01 | 2.00    | 2.00    | 2.00      |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC103696   | S484             | 2020-06-03 | 2021-01-01 | 1.00    | 1.00    | 1.00      |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| HC103696   | S488             | 2020-06-03 | 2021-01-01 | 0.50    | 0.50    | 0.50      |
+------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: You could try using your query as a subquery and add a column such as `CASE WHEN costtype = N'H107' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS amountH107` and afterwards create a query and `SUM` this new column...

Comment: You can add `case` expressions inside aggregation functions. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63558503/creating-a-calculated-column-based-on-the-flag-tsql/63558634).

Comment: I am almost there. Edited my post (see below). Following code almost does all I need: CASE WHEN C.RENTALCOSTTYPEID = 'H104' 
THEN SUM(CASE WHEN C.RENTALCOSTTYPEID LIKE 'H%' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0  END) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CONTRACTID, C.VALIDFROM, C.VALIDTO) 
ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN C.RENTALCOSTTYPEID LIKE 'H%' THEN 0 ELSE c.amount  END) OVER (PARTITION BY C.RENTALCOSTTYPEID, C.CONTRACTID, C.VALIDFROM, C.VALIDTO)
END AS TESTCOLUMN

Comment: why first three rows have different `ENDRESULT` ? they have same `CONTRACTID`, `VALIDFROM` and `VALIDTO` and also they have a 'H104' in column `RENTALCOSTTYPEID` shouldn't be all 446.72?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display aggregated values and non-aggregated values *on the same row*. While achieving this in a single `select` statement might be possible, it is easier to combine a few `select`'s in a one query.

For example, if you calculate the sums for the rentalcosttypeid `H%` rows that have a `H104` row among them in a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE), then you can join with those results later on.

**Sample data**

```
declare @PMCCONTRACTLINE table
(
    CONTRACTID nvarchar(10),
    RENTALCOSTTYPEID nvarchar(5),
    VALIDFROM date,
    VALIDTO date,
    AMOUNT money
);

insert into @PMCCONTRACTLINE (CONTRACTID, RENTALCOSTTYPEID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO, AMOUNT) values
('HC018453', 'H104',  '2020-07-01', '2021-01-01', 775.08 ),
('HC018453', 'H110',  '2020-07-01', '2021-01-01', -328.36),
('HC018453', 'V446',  '2020-07-01', '2021-01-01', 48.00  ),
('HC055533', 'H105',  '2020-07-01', '2021-01-01', 330.00 ),
('HC055533', 'H105H', '2019-07-01', '2020-06-30', 330.00 ),
('HC103696', 'H104',  '2020-06-03', '2021-01-01', 867.00 ),
('HC103696', 'S468',  '2020-06-03', '2021-01-01', 2.00   ),
('HC103696', 'S484',  '2020-06-03', '2021-01-01', 1.00   ),
('HC103696', 'S488',  '2020-06-03', '2021-01-01', 0.50   );
```

**Solution**

Defines `cte_SumH104` as a result set for `H%` rows with a `H104` row among them for the same ContractID.

```
with cte_SumH104 as
(
    select cl.CONTRACTID, sum(cl.AMOUNT) as 'SUMH'
    from @PMCCONTRACTLINE cl
    where cl.RENTALCOSTTYPEID like 'H%'
      and exists (  select top 1 'x'
                    from @PMCCONTRACTLINE clh104
                    where clh104.CONTRACTID = cl.CONTRACTID
                      and clh104.RENTALCOSTTYPEID = 'H104' )
    group by cl.CONTRACTID
)
select  cl.*,
        s.SUMH,
        case
            when cl.RENTALCOSTTYPEID = 'H104' then s.SUMH
            when cl.RENTALCOSTTYPEID like 'H%' and s.SUMH is not null then 0
            else cl.AMOUNT
        end as 'TEST'
from @PMCCONTRACTLINE cl
left join cte_SumH104 s
    on s.CONTRACTID = cl.CONTRACTID;
```

**Result**

```
CONTRACTID  RENTALCOSTTYPEID  VALIDFROM   VALIDTO     AMOUNT    SUMH     TEST
----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- --------- -------- --------
HC018453    H104              2020-07-01  2021-01-01  775,08    446,72   446,72
HC018453    H110              2020-07-01  2021-01-01  -328,36   446,72   0,00
HC018453    V446              2020-07-01  2021-01-01  48,00     446,72   48,00
HC055533    H105              2020-07-01  2021-01-01  330,00    NULL     330,00
HC055533    H105H             2019-07-01  2020-06-30  330,00    NULL     330,00
HC103696    H104              2020-06-03  2021-01-01  867,00    867,00   867,00
HC103696    S468              2020-06-03  2021-01-01  2,00      867,00   2,00
HC103696    S484              2020-06-03  2021-01-01  1,00      867,00   1,00
HC103696    S488              2020-06-03  2021-01-01  0,50      867,00   0,50
```